# Flutter FutureBuilder, Future.wait with Geolocator Future and another future not fetching data

Tags: flutter, geolocation

It is already a week since I started struggling with the problem so I am totally at a loss.
In my code - please see below - I need to resolve two futures to build the page. One - from Geolocator package to get user location for the map, the other is a list of jobs /activities available for the user in the location. The activity / job future also relies on getting location of the user and then fetches the data form API.

The problem I am facing and have tried several ways (both Location and Geolocator packages) but the problem I get is that the futureSnapshot connection completes (goes to 'done') but the location part of the future is null.
Even though I created a Future method based on Pieter's advice I still get

> "W/Geolocator(12158): Location permissions not part of permissions
> send to onRequestPermissionsResult method.
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12158): reportFullscreenMode on inexistent
> InputConnection"

The Future created is and now it is used by fetchJobsFuture as well as provided to the MapCard widget

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Future<Position> getUserPosition() async {
  var _permissionGranted = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

  if (_permissionGranted != LocationPermission.always ||
      _permissionGranted != LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
    await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  }

  final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  return position;
}
```

And this is the entire code for the page:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      static const double _desiredSplit =
          0.6; // ONLY one after the decimal point!!!
      double currentSplit = _desiredSplit;
      static const double _minMapFragment = 0.04;
      double listTopBarHeight = 42.0;
    
      Future<JobList> fetchJobsFuture;
      JobList currentListOfJobs;
    
      Future<Position> userPositionFuture;
      Position userPosition;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        currentListOfJobs = Provider.of<JobList>(context, listen: false);
    
        getUserPosition().then((value) => userPosition = value).then((_) {
          fetchJobsFuture = currentListOfJobs.getCurrentJobList();
        });
    
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: fetchJobsFuture,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<JobList> futureSnaphot) {
                if (!futureSnaphot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Container(
                          child: MapCard(
                            latitude: userPosition.latitude,
                            longitude: userPosition.longitude,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 300,
                        child: ListCard(
                          jobList: futureSnaphot.data,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated -  Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Putting futures in a Future.wait means that they will be executed in parralel.
So to first get the permission and then the location you need to do them after eachother for instance using async await:

```dart
Future<returntype> gerJobs(JobList currentListOfJobs) async{
  await geolocationPermission;
  final location = await geolocation;
  jobs = await currentListOfJobs.getCurrentJobList(location);
  return jobs
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. This solution is very logical and elegant but it doesn't work for me. I think it may be because the "fetchJobsFuture" also needs location and this way I still get two requests at a time. Any idea how to correct this without rebuilding much of my code?

Comment: Then you can just also await that call after the location

Comment: Hmmm - even after awaiting in the build for the Position and then calling fetchJobsFuture I am stuck. I am at a loss. Here is what I tried: 
`getUserPosition().then((value) => userPosition = value).then((_) {
        fetchJobsFuture = currentListOfJobs.getCurrentJobList();
    });`
Now I use a FutureBuilder with one future and the position is supplied as is.

Comment: The post is now updated with the most up to date code. Any futher guidance would be much appreciated :) Thanks Pieter!

Comment: You are now calling the future in the build method which is not something you ever want to do (the build method should not have any side effects. Instead update your method like I’ll put in the edit of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution somebody suggested  - thx. Katarina!
The Future.wait[] was not working for me since my JobList future also called on location so I got the conflict with simultaneous call to Geolocator and its permissions. The answer in such cases is to nest FutureBuilders in one another not use Future.wait[] so that one future resolves before the other.
The code below is a rather hasty and inelegant example - please excuse this, but it conveys the point I hope:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  JobList currentListOfJobs;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentListOfJobs = Provider.of<JobList>(context, listen: false);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Position> positionSnapshot) {
            if (positionSnapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return FutureBuilder(
                  future: currentListOfJobs.getCurrentJobList(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<JobList> jobListFutureSnaphot) {
                    if (jobListFutureSnaphot.connectionState !=
                        ConnectionState.done) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 200,
                            child: Container(
                              child: MapCardWithMarkers(
                                heightRemainingForMap: 200,
                                latitude: positionSnapshot.data.latitude,
                                longitude: positionSnapshot.data.longitude,
                                currentJobList: jobListFutureSnaphot.data,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 200,
                            child: ListCard(
                              listTopBarHeight: 20,
                              jobList: jobListFutureSnaphot.data,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  });
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldnt nest future builders like this, this logic does not belong in the widget tree (and you dont want to repeat yourself with the loading indicator)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of both shortcomings - nesting and calling the future in the build method. I will play with this, but I guess my next step will be Qubit / BLOC anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was digging more into the problem and ended up asking the guys who develop the Geolocator package what could be causing the:

```
W/Activity(24892): Can reqeust only one set of permissions at a time
W/Geolocator(24892): Location permissions not part of permissions send to onRequestPermissionsResult method.
```

If you are interested in the ideas - here is the full thread: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/661

To make it short. If you encounter a similar issue:

1. be aware that builder calls futures many times in quick
   succession (each rebuild) so that, as in case of Geolocator, a request for permissions may be generated while the previous is still resolving,
2. in more complex apps several pieces of the app logic may need to access Geolocator's location. Therefore make sure that you know what parts of the code are calling Location and when ...